# insert variable into sql value

Tags: android, sqlite

```
String ans1= "Apple";

myDb.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +
               TABLE_NAME + " Values (ans1);");
```

It just doesn't work this way.. why?? I need a simple way to do this, I don't want use class that's confusing for a beginner like me, possible?

Answer (score 5):

Your insert statement should read something like

```
"INSERT INTO " + TABLE_NAME + " VALUES ('" + ans1 + "');"
```

Notice the single quotes that wrap ans1, if you are inserting a string value into an SQL table it should be wrapped in single quotes.

Comment: @Lucifer, Just interested to know why you edited my answer to only remove "Hope that Helps".  I am knew to Stack Overflow, and was just been friendly.

Comment: sure, there should not be tag lines added, that's why i removed it, nothing else.

Answer (score 4):

Try this example :

```
public long insertValue(String value1, String value2) {
        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put(KEY_VALUE1, value1);
        initialValues.put(KEY_VALUE2, value2);

        return mDb.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
    }
```

Comment: what is the KEY_VALUE there means?

Comment: I declare my column on the top ( `public static final String KEY_VALUE1 = "value1";` )

Answer (score 0):

values should be something like

values("+ans1+");

observe ans1 is inside quote.

Note: raw sql statements are prone to sql injection attacks.

Comment: Data security is my kryptonite.  When developing web applications it has caused me many sleepless nights.  I don't give it much thought when developing a local database such as this.  Should I be more concerned about it?

Answer (score 0):

To inject the VALUE of variable into a sql statement you need to end your quotes before the variable + the variable + open your quotes again.  For a String value you will also need to add single quotes around the variable.

```
myDb.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +
           TABLE_NAME + " Values ('" + ans1 + "');");
```

Answer (score 0):

You are inserting variable's value in to table, hence you have to use variable ANS out of the `"` ( double cots ), like below,

```
String ans1= "Apple";

myDb.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_NAME + " Values ( '" + ans1 + "' );");
```

It is same as your have not use TABLE_NAME variable inside the `"`.

Answer (score 0):

For me i wanted to have last inserted id using select from database and then insert new data into database, the select query is used that function

```
pagesClass.getLastID('users', function(err, id){var id = id}
```

or you can use direct id which was returned by function

```
User.createUser = function (result){
var pagesClass = new PagesClass();
pagesClass.getLastID('users', function(err, id){
    conn.query("INSERT INTO users(id, name, email, password) VALUE('"+id+"', 'djsk"+id+"', 'yes@gmail.com"+id+"', 'bercove') ", function (err, res){
        if(err)
            result(null, err);
        else
            result(null, res);
    });
});
};
```

those id into name column and email column was showing how you can also add the variable to the other columns